# Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time (golang)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I'm deploying an app on App Engine Flexible in golang. It deploys correctly if I use the hello world example for "main.go", so it's not a config issue.

The logical conclusion would be that there's an issue with my app (the prod project). However I've deployed the *same* code on a separate staging project, and that's working fine.

In this project, all steps succeed, but then I get "Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time", when traffic is being set to the new service.

The only thing I can think of is that my app uses a CloudSQL instance (Admin API enabled!), and that's set correctly in staging but not prod. I don't see how though. The key puzzle is why the same code is working in staging.

What are the exact reasons one sees this error message? How can I find out more?

Many thanks

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

# Update with Redis instance network name
network:
  name: default

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

handlers:

# All URLs are handled by the Go application script
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
  secure: always


beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: [hidden]
```

Comment: Your question is missing details. Do you have two projects? One project has App Engine and Cloud SQL and this one works? Do you have another project with App Engine accessing Cloud SQL in the other project and this does not work? In Cloud SQL, did you enable the other project "Authorize apps in other projects"? What does Stackdriver show you for the non-working configuration? Edit your question with the details and to clearly explain your configuration.

Comment: Note: Do not answer my comment. Edit your question to improve the details.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused because you are trying to configure `handlers` in App Engine Flexible.

The `handlers` section is only configurable in [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/config/appref#handlers_element). Check the app.yaml flexible Go [runtime reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/reference/app-yaml) for details on how the file should look like.

I hope this approach helps you.